# How to add a new column to a dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I  am generating a random data from normal distribution.
Second, I want to add a column named Class that classify this values into a `class=1.`

After that, I will generate data from uniform distribution and classify to a `classe=-1.`

Finally, I'd like to set this two datasets into one. Where `x=(generated values, 50 from normal and 50 from uniform) and y=(Class= 1 or -1)`.

```
a=np.random.uniform(0,1,(50,1))
a['Classe']='1'

b=np.random.normal(2,1,(50,1))
a['Classe']='-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.concatenate((np.random.uniform(size=50,), np.random.normal(2,1, 50))), 
    "y": np.array([-1]*50 + [1]*50)
    })
```